# How to implement a code behind function using View Model?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

FYI, I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658499/calling-a-method-in-views-codebehind-from-viewmodel) in S.O, but it's answer had a broken link attached to it. It didn't help me.

This is what I have.

Then:

I had a StackPanel in my View. Using code-behind, in it's tap event, I wrote a function for doing a specific task.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="spnl" Tapped="spnl_Tapped" >
   <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Image  Source="{Binding imgImage}"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
  </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Now:

I have a StackPanel in my view. And I have written a class in my ViewModel.

```
 public class ClassIWroteinViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {   
        public ImageSource imgImage { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }      
        private async void spnl_Tapped()
        {
           IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> PicturesLibrary = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFoldersAsync();                
        }
    }
```

My question is how to implement this spnl_Tapped()??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using **Behaviors SDK** to call a method when an event is triggered. Add a reference to the Behaviors SDK (from the extensions) and then add these references to the XAML page.

```
xmlns:Interactions="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions"
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
```

You can call the viewmodel method by using `CallMethodAction`  on `EventTriggerBehavior`

```
<StackPanel>
  <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Image  Source="{Binding imgImage}"/>
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
 </Grid>
     <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                <Core:CallMethodAction MethodName="spnl_tapped"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</StackPanel>
```

**EDIT:** There is also another way. Have a command with a delegate to `spnl_tapped` in the viewmodel.

```
public class ClassIWroteInViewModel:ViewModelBase{

       public RelayCommand TapCommand
       {
             get;
             private set;
       }

       public ClassIWroteInViewModel()
       {
             TapCommand=new RelayCommand(spnl_Tapped);//delegate to spnl_tapped viewmodel method
       }

       public ImageSource imgImage { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }      

       private async void spnl_Tapped()
      {
             IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> PicturesLibrary = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFoldersAsync();                
      }

 }
```

Now in the code-behind..

```
private void spnl_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var vm=this.DataContext as ClassIWroteInViewModel; //get the view model
     vm.TapCommand.Execute(null);//execute the command
}
```

Comment: I have used Behaviors SDK once. Is there any other method (pure code) (may be using commands) by which this can be achieved? @Sridhar

Comment: So, inside spnl_tapped, after 1)get the view model 2) execute the command, I should write the functionality. Right? @Sridhar

Comment: The command will call the async method you defined in the view model. You can write your functionality there. So you need not include more functionality in the code-behind method.

Comment: Ok. That's great. But delegate to spnl_tapped viewmodel method produces an error. Says Tapped is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'. I am new to this C# world. @Sridhar

Comment: I've edited the post to include code for the whole view model. It should work. The error probably occurred because `Tapped` is a event name and I've changed the command name.