# How to deal with too-logic packed controls in MVVM/WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using AvalonEdit for displaying formatted text. The application is written in MVVM architecture in C#/WPF.

The problem is that the AvalonEdit control contains a lot of logic, which is accessible only from the control itself. So, say, I want to deal with current selection - for that I have to reach `editor.TextArea.Selection` - this is not accessible from the viewmodel.

Now my architecture may be shortly described as:

- Main view model contains list of `DocumentViewModel`s
- `DocumentViewModel` contains `TextDocument`
- List of `DocumentViewModel`s is bound to `DockingManager` to be displayed as a list of tabs
- `DockingManager`'s DataTemplate is set to my control containing the `TextEditor`
- `TextDocument` from `DocumentViewModel` is bound to `Document` property of `TextEditor`

Say, that I want to access selected text from the main window's viewmodel. I can reach for `DocumentViewModel` of the currently active document, but I have no way of accessing the control, which presents it (it's created and managed via the DataTemplate mechanisms of `DockingManager`)

[image: Architecture diagram]

Usually I solved this kind of problem by passing view to viewmodel via interface - such that viewmodel might have asked view (indirectly) to do something I couldn't bind or pass via commands. But since I have no control over creation of document views, I have no way of using such solution.

How can I access the TextEditor from MainWindowViewModel having its DocumentViewModel only? And how to do that without breaking the MVVM model? (obviously I may try to reach the control via visual tree, but that's hacking and I definitely want to avoid it)

Comment: There is no need to access controls from viewmodel. Add a property `SelectedText` to the viewmodel servicing that control, which will be set (also read?) by view in its code-behind (view [knows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26038700/1997232) about viewmodel), done.

Comment: @Sinatr, how would then viewmodel get information about selection since it cannot ask view anything? Should view update the selection each time it is changed? If we extend that to all possible flags, options etc., it will cause significant performance drop. And we're talking also about calling methods, accessing non-bindable properties etc.

Comment: Viewmodel *can* ask view using events (view replies by subscribing and changing viewmodel/`CustomEventArgs` properties). A better idea if view continuously synchronize itself with viewmodel. Each time selection is changed view has to change value of `SelectedText` property of viewmodel. And yes, rather than having `AvalonEdit` in viewmodel you have add everything needed (by viewmodel) individually to a viewmodel. If control is complex, consider to make a special viewmodel, servicing only this control (rather *any* control with *same* functionality), and add it as property to main viewmodel.