# .NET MAUI: Dynamic behaviour of graphic elements when using MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui

For the animation of UI elements like a progress bar, even in [Microsofts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/progressbar?view=net-maui-7.0#animate-a-progressbar), there are always suggestions that (only) work from code behind, like this:

```
await progressBar.ProgressTo(0.75, 500, Easing.Linear);
```

I could not find a way to do this from a ViewModel, as it is not possible (and not intended) to access XAML elements from there. I tried to this with data binding, using BindableProperty. Could not get it to work. So, am I holding it wrong, or is it not possible?

I created a Drawable class:

```
public class ProgressArcDrawable : GraphicsView, IDrawable
{

    public double ArcProgress
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ArcProgressProperty);
        set => SetValue(ArcProgressProperty, value);
    }

    public float Stroke
    {
        get => (float)GetValue(StrokeProperty);
        set => SetValue(StrokeProperty, value);
    }

    public Color ArcColor
    {
        get => (Color)GetValue(ArcColorProperty);
        set => SetValue(ArcColorProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ArcProgressProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ArcProgress), typeof(double), typeof(ProgressArcDrawable));

    public static readonly BindableProperty StrokeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Stroke), typeof(float), typeof(ProgressArcDrawable));

    public static readonly BindableProperty ArcColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ArcColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ProgressArcDrawable));

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        var endAngle = 90 - (int)Math.Round(ArcProgress * 360, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        canvas.StrokeColor = ArcColor;
        canvas.StrokeSize = Stroke;
        canvas.DrawArc(Stroke / 2, Stroke / 2, (dirtyRect.Width - Stroke), (dirtyRect.Height - Stroke), 90, endAngle, false, false);
    }
}
```

As I am using the MVVM toolkit, I created ObservableProperties in my viewmodel like so:

```
[ObservableProperty]
double arcProgress;
```

In my view I integrate the drawable with the data bindings:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <drawables:ProgressArcDrawable
        x:Key="progressArcDrawable"
        ArcProgress="{Binding ArcProgress}"
        Stroke="20"
        ArcColor="{Binding Scrum.ScrumTheme.AccentColor}" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
...
<Grid>
       <GraphicsView
                Drawable="{StaticResource progressArcDrawable}"
                HeightRequest="350"
                WidthRequest="350" />
</Grid>
```

The only binding that works, is the one that sets the stroke as a discrete value. The AccentColor binding works on other elements on the page, so there is data in there, but it does not work for the drawable. And thats the same for the ArcProgress, which should change the progress arc once a second.

Comment: Have you already searched for third party components on nuget.org that might do what you need?

Comment: For Perform Animations in MVVM you usually just create methods in your View and then in your VM you create Actions that trigger those methods...

Comment: @ewerspej Thanks for that hint. I see, that you offer a progress bar there as well. But all stuff that can be found do not answer my primary question: How to control that from the viewmodel? If I control it from code behind, I can use the .Invalidate method on the xaml element to redraw it when it changes. Can't do that from the viewmodel either ...

Comment: Like Freaky Ali correctly pointed out, you can call View methods from the ViewModel without breaking MVVM by applying inversion of control (IoC). You could define a delegate in your ViewModel which is View-agnostic and set the delegate in your View's code behind. Now, usually using a property binding should actually suffice, I don't know why your binding doesn't work. It could be related to the fact that the `Drawable` instance comes from a `ResourceDictionary`.

Comment: My best guess is to add the drawable in a different way. Instead of assigning it as a resource, you could instantiate it directly:  `<GraphicsView.Drawable><drawables:ProgressArcDrawable .../></GraphicsView.Drawable>`

Comment: [Calling a Method in View's CodeBehind from ViewModel? / Registering an action in viewmodel from view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67070562/199364) is one way to have code in viewmodel able to trigger code in view.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I will have a closer look after Christmas. Happy holidays all!

Comment: @Lilly BTW, how are you updating the properties in your ViewModel? Make sure to use the autogenerated capitalized identifiers.

Comment: @ewerspej Good point, but yes, I am using the capitalized ids from the toolkits auto-generated code

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve That looked promising, but I couldn't get it to work. In the viewmodel I have a function, that updates the progressarc every second (which works fine when everything is in code-behind). I added an action: public Action<bool> UpdateProgress { get; set; } and call it everytime another second is elapsed, it should then set the new value for the end angle on the arc and call Invalidate() on the drawable. But it does invoke the function only once, after that, it just goes over it. Unfortunately I can't even find something in the MS docs about that mechanism ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead using the `Drawable` with a `StaticResource`:

```xml
<Grid>
    <GraphicsView
        HeightRequest="350"
        WidthRequest="350">
        <GraphicsView.Drawable>
            <drawables:ProgressArcDrawable
                ArcProgress="{Binding ArcProgress}"
                Stroke="20"
                ArcColor="{Binding Scrum.ScrumTheme.AccentColor}" />
        </GraphicsView.Drawable>
    </GraphicsView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That didn't make a difference ...

Comment: Okay, then I'm at a loss. Maybe try using SkiaSharp instead. I'm usually working with a `SKCanvasView`. I inherit from it and then I can implement bindable properties.

Comment: To get this finished, I have implemented the logic for this view in the code behind file now. Its a pity that MS documentation is so meager on this ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for this, here is how I did it.

```cs
public class ProgressArcDrawable : GraphicsView, IDrawable
{
    public ProgressArcDrawable()
    {
        Drawable = this;
    }

    //...
}
```

in your XAML file

```xml
<local:ProgressArcDrawable ArcProgress ="{Binding ProgressValue}"
       HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"/>
```